# Columnas con el mismo nombre usando Dapper

Tags: c#, ms-access, orm, dapper

Soy nuevo usando Dapper (en este caso lo estoy usando con una base de datos en Microsoft Access)

Mi problema, se da debido a que estoy haciendo un join de dos tablas que tienen una columna con el mismo nombre, mi base de datos es algo así.

Registros

```
ID            |  Autonumeric
TareaM_Id     |  Numeric
Fecha         |  Date/Time
```

Macro_tarea

```
ID            |  Autonumeric
Nombre        |  Short Text
```

Por lo cual, en C# lo mapee de la siguiente manera

```
public class Registros
{        
    public int ID { get; set; }        
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }    
    public int TareaM_Id { get; set; }    
    public MacroTarea Mac { get;set; }
}

public class Macro_tarea
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }       
    public string Nombre { get; set; }    
    public virtual ICollection<Registros> Registros { get; set; }
}
```

El vínculo en estas tablas es que una Macro tarea tiene muchos registros (mediante `Macro_tarea.ID = Registros.TareaM_Id`)

Por lo que utilizo Dapper de la siguiente manera:

```
string sql = @"SELECT Registros.* , Macro_tarea.*
            FROM Registros INNER JOIN Macro_tarea on Registros.TareaM_Id = Macro_tarea.ID
            WHERE Fecha = @Fecha";

using (IDbConnection db = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
    var result = db.Query<Registros,Macro_tarea, Registros>(sql, 
        (reg,mac) =>
        {
            reg.MacroTarea = mac;
            return reg;
        }
        ,new { @Fecha = new DateTime(2019, 1, 4).Date }
        , splitOn: "Macro_tarea.ID")
        .AsList();
```

El asunto es que ambos campos (`Registros.ID` y `Macro_tarea.ID`) llegan `null` a menos que modifique la propiedad en alguna de las clases y utilice un alias en la query para que coincida.

La pregunta es, ¿Existe algún método para lograr que Dapper diferencie ambos ID sin la necesidad de cambiar el nombre de la propiedad?

Comment: probaste con `splitOn: "ID"`?

Comment: @g3rv4 Sí, pero se lanza la excepción como si no encontrase la columna `When using the multi-mapping APIs ensure you set the splitOn param if you have keys other than Id`

Comment: y usar `SELECT Registros.*, 1 Splitter, Macro_tarea.*` con `splitOn: "Splitter"`?

Answer (score 0):

Llegué a la solución de mi problema utilizando el ''mapeo personalizado de columnas'' o Custom Columns Mapping.

Una implementación funcional puede ser la siguiente:

Primero, definimos un `Diccionary<string,string>` con el nombre de la columna como `key`, y el nombre de la propiedad como `value`

```
IDictionary<string, string> columnMaps = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                { "Macro_tarea.ID", "ID" },
                { "Registros.ID", "ID" }
            };
```

Luego, definimos un delegado para obtener el objeto `PropertyInfo` de la propiedad a la que pretendemos que se asigne el alias del diccionario anterior

```
var mapper = new Func<Type, string, PropertyInfo>((type, columnName) =>
            {
                if (columnMaps.ContainsKey(columnName))
                    return type.GetProperty(columnMaps[columnName]);
                else
                    return type.GetProperty(columnName);
            });
```

Ahora, definimos un objeto que implemente la interfaz `ITypeMap` usando `CustomPropertyTypeMap`

```
ITypeMap MacroTareaMapper = new CustomPropertyTypeMap(typeof(Macro_tarea),
                (type, columnName) => mapper(type, columnName));

ITypeMap RegistrosMapper = new CustomPropertyTypeMap(typeof(Registros),
                (type, columnName) => mapper(type, columnName));
```

En mi caso son 2, uno para la clase `Registros` y otro para la clase `Macro_tarea`

Por último seteamos los custom column mapping

```
SqlMapper.SetTypeMap(typeof(Macro_tarea), MacroTareaMapper);
SqlMapper.SetTypeMap(typeof(Registros), RegistrosMapper);
```

De esta manera, al ejecutar la query, las propiedades se asignarán de manera correcta.

---

***Solución 2***

Otra posibilidad para solucionar este problema es usar la extensión [Dapper.FluentMap](https://dapper-tutorial.net/dapper-fluentmap), que es bastante mas sencilla y requiere de menos código.

Se implementa de la siguiente manera:

Creamos una clase, que herede de `EntityMap<T>` y usando el método `Map` definimos a que columna le corresponde cada propiedad. Por ejemplo,

```
internal class Macro_tareaMap : EntityMap<Macro_tarea>
{
       internal Macro_tareaMap()
       {
            //Mi propiedad ID esta asociada a la columna Macro_tarea.ID
            Map(x => x.ID).ToColumn("Macro_tarea.ID");
       }
}
```

Luego, basta con registrar la clase de la siguiente manera:

```
FluentMapper.Initialize((config) => 
{
    config.AddMap(new Macro_tareaMap());
});
```

De esta manera, se llegaría al mismo resultado (sólo aplicado para la clase `Macro_tarea`)

[Fuente (de ambas soluciones)](https://medium.com/dapper-net/custom-columns-mapping-1cd45dfd51d6)