# ¿Cómo hago una consulta OneToMany en Dapper?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, .net, dapper

Resulta que tengo dos Identidades, Superhero y Team, un Team puede tener muchos Superheroes dentro de sí... pero un Superheroe sólo pertenece a un Team, adjunto clases:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El script de la base de datos es el siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE Teams(
id_team int identity PRIMARY KEY,
Nameteam nvarchar(MAX)
)

CREATE TABLE SuperHeroes(
id_hero int identity PRIMARY KEY,
Nickname nvarchar(MAX),
Firstname nvarchar(MAX),
Lastname nvarchar(MAX),
Poder nvarchar(MAX),
team_id int,
FOREIGN KEY (team_id) REFERENCES Teams(id_team)
)
```

Y mi método Get para Teams es el siguiente:

```
        [HttpGet("teams")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<List<Team>>> GetAllTeams()
        {
            using var connection = new SqlConnection(_configDapper.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
            string sql = "SELECT sp.* , t.* FROM SuperHeroes sp INNER JOIN Teams t on sp.team_id = t.id_team";

            var teamDictionary = new Dictionary<int, Team>();

            var list = await connection.QueryAsync<Team, SuperHero, Team>(sql,
            (t, s) =>
            {
                Team teamAux;

                if (!teamDictionary.TryGetValue(t.id_team, out teamAux))
                {
                    teamAux = t;
                    teamAux.Members = new List<SuperHero>();
                    teamDictionary.Add(teamAux.id_team, teamAux);
                }
                teamAux.Members.Add(s);
                return teamAux;
            },
            splitOn: "id_hero,id_team");
            return Ok(list);
        }
```

El cual me arroja null en el return:

```
[
  {
    "id_team": 0,
    "nameteam": "",
    "members": [
      {
        "id_hero": 0,
        "nickname": "",
        "firstname": "",
        "lastname": "",
        "poder": "",
        "team_id": null
      },
      {
        "id_hero": 0,
        "nickname": "",
        "firstname": "",
        "lastname": "",
        "poder": "",
        "team_id": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id_team": 0,
    "nameteam": "",
    "members": [
      {
        "id_hero": 0,
        "nickname": "",
        "firstname": "",
        "lastname": "",
        "poder": "",
        "team_id": null
      },
```

Sinceramente ese método Get lo hice mirando otros códigos pero no me funciona.. y tampoco entiendo lo que el método TryGetValue

He visto que utilizan esta manera de traer los datos en la documentación https://dapper-tutorial.net/result-multi-mapping#example-query-multi-mapping-one-to-many sin embargo a mi no me funciona :/

Gracias por leer.

Comment: Bueno.. es cierto que hay un if y si no entra al if, que va a devolver en ese caso? Pero hay algo que no entiendo.. que datos quisiste traer??? absolutamente todos los que?

Comment: Quiero traer todos los Equipos (Team) con sus respectivos miembros (SuperHero), aquí tengo una versión más actualizada del método pero me retorna vacío todo..

Comment: Aunque no esta mal.. no suena a buena idea... es mas.. porque directamente no traes todos los superheroes con su team asociado, y sin hacer ningun split, lo pones como queres en pantalla?

Comment: Uhm no te entendí, pues, si realizo la consulta sql en mi sqlsv me funciona bien. Sin embargo, la forma de dapper para asociar un listado de una entidad perteneciente a otra es esa que intenté hacer, sin embargo no me funciona:/  si intento un select* de team me traerá en null los miembros

Comment: dapper tiene una opcion split, que es por donde parte este tipo de querys. no la tengo de memoria y no puedo contestar ahora.. lo que decia antes, era que no entendia el sentido de este query... si estas devolviendo todo, porque arrancas por equipos, en lugar de devolver solo los superheroes junto al nombre de equipos... es lo mismo, pero al reves...

Comment: Cuando intento retornar heroes, en el campo team_id me suelta el arreglo del equipo en null y también con el campo members :/ https://prnt.sc/Oa2mtLTi_bn3 , https://prnt.sc/39vBFqAF3IDu

Comment: Estas usando dapper de una forma muy rara.. mira mis repos, y vas a ver en las apis ejemplos mucho mas simples de como usar dapper....

Comment: Muchas gracias por el dato Gbianchi lo cierto es que soy muy nuevo, me podrías indicar el nombre del repositorio por favor

Comment: Leistte la documentacion de dapper? parece que solo miraste un ejemplo muy complejo.. el link a git esta en el perfil...

Comment: mira esta respuesta tambien https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/227763/324